# Batch file - text file Printing order

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

i have some 100 text files in a folder `temp_files` and this is how i am printing them

```
        for /f %%B in ('dir temp_files\*.txt /b') do (

    start /min notepad /P temp_files\%%B
    )
```

the files are printing fine, but they are not printing in order. for example, when i echo the output like this

```
        for /f %%B in ('dir temp_files\*.txt /b') do (

    echo start /min notepad /P temp_files\%%B>>print_order.txt
    )
```

in print_oreder.txt the order is correct, 
this is how the  **print_order.txt** looks:

```
start /min notepad /P temp_files\location_1_product_1.txt
start /min notepad /P temp_files\location_1_product_2.txt
start /min notepad /P temp_files\location_1_product_3.txt
start /min notepad /P temp_files\location_2_product_1.txt
start /min notepad /P temp_files\location_2_product_2.txt
start /min notepad /P temp_files\location_2_product_3.txt
```

but when the actual print comes, it is not in order, it is random order. this is how the actual print is coming,
**actual printing order**

```
location_1_product_1.txt
location_1_product_3.txt
location_2_product_2.txt
```

is there any way to print in order like this,
**expecting print order:**

```
location_1_product_1.txt
location_1_product_2.txt
location_1_product_3.txt
location_2_product_1.txt
location_2_product_2.txt
location_2_product_3.txt
```

please help. thank you.

Comment: The `start` command runs the notepad asynchronously to your script, so the order in which those programs begin depends  on Windows scheduler.  Either don't use the start command, or check if the /wait option to the start command gives the result you want.

Comment: @mao, thank you, noted.

Comment: So you don't have any files with numbers greater than 9?  If so, you will run into problems with the printing order again because the dir and for commands do not output in numerical order like Windows Explorer does.  Another option for printing would be to map your printer to LPT1 and then you could in theory use redirection to output your files directly to the printer without having to use Notepad to print them.  That is at least how we did it back in the old days. Not necessarily guaranteed to work with newer printers but still does work with my old HP LaserJet's (3,4 & 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a timing problem (you open some 100 processes, they are not guaranteed to execute in a particular order). Add a `/wait` to wait for each process to finish before the next is started:

```
start /min /wait notepad /P temp_files\%%B
```

(Note: this will make your script much slower, but you have to wait for the printer anyways..)

Comment: thank you, i am trying this solution now, will update shortly

Comment: one doubt, if i echo the output to a text file and type the text file, will it be faster, is it a good practice? as i can see the order is proper if i echo, for example, `echo start /min notepad /P temp_files\location_1_product_1.txt
echo start /min notepad /P temp_files\location_1_product_2.txt>>print_order.txt
echo start /min notepad /P temp_files\location_1_product_3.txt>>print_order.txt
and then, `type print_order.txt`, i havent try this, kindly advice

Comment: no need for `notepad` (it's contraproductive): `for /f %%B in ('dir temp_files\*.txt /b') do type %%B>>print_order.txt`. And THEN `notepad -p print_order.txt` But this will print without formfeeds (no "new Page" for each document).

Comment: i have tried your solution with 1500 files, it took 12 minutes to print. but the order is perfect. it was not at all a delay. im just thinking of speeding up the printing, please advice if we can speed up the printing process, is there any other options?

Comment: use a faster printer?

Comment: sorry, i mean the wait command makes it little slow, but i would say it is a perfect solution. so just thought of checking if some other options.

Comment: you could try to skip the `start` command and just use `notepad /P temp_files\%%B` to avoid creating a new process for each file, but I think, it's starting Notepad itself, which takes it's time.